# Listening to a WebSocket connection through prototypes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I have spent a couple weeks on this issue and I can’t seem to find a resolution. Here is the use case. I am developing a chrome extension, one of the main purposes of this extension is to detect when a WebSocket opens or closes. I have looked at the HTML5 spec for WebSockets, they expose the following related methods/events:

```
WebSocket.prototype.readyState = 0;
WebSocket.prototype.onopen = 0;
WebSocket.prototype.onerror = 0;
WebSocket.prototype.onclose = 0;
function WebSocket(url,protocols) {}
WebSocket.prototype.close = function(code,reason) {};
```

Since I don’t have access to the individual instance from within the extension, I have to rely on wrapping these prototypes to find out when they are called. For example:

```
WebSocket.prototype.close = function (close) {
    console.log("Closing socket....");
    return function (code, reason) {
        return close.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}(WebSocket.prototype.close);
```

However, what I really want to do is somehow wrap or register listeners for onopen, onerror, or onclose. Unfortunately I do not know how to do this. I tried a bunch of different approaches. The approach above works for 'close', but they do not offer 'open', which I am dependent on. The most promising idea, which did not work, was the following:

```
WebSocket.prototype.constructor = function (constructor) {
    debugger;
    console.log("Register all my events here!");
    constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}(WebSocket.prototype.constructor);
```

Unfortunately, I was never able to hit a breakpoint, or see console logs, which led me to believe I was doing something wrong.

As a last resort, I tried to play around with Object.Observe(), but was unable to observe the prototype:

```
Object.observe(WebSocket.prototype.readyState, function (changes) {
    console.log("Ready state");
});

Object.observe(WebSocket.prototype.onopen, function (changes) {
    console.log("On open");
});
```

So, to sum things up, I have tried a few different approaches, but ultimately I have hit a wall. In the end my goal is to detect when a WebSocket opens or closes by listening to any of the exposed methods or events. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
Here is a fiddle, including the suggestions below:

http://jsfiddle.net/s35zpfq9/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Are you not instantiating the WebSocket yourself then?

Comment: @AdamJeffers correct. I am more of less trying to listen for events without the actual instance. I can do this fine with send(), just not the other events. I will updated my question with a fiddle.

Comment: I'm getting an alert for all the events you are listening for when running your fiddle... what browser etc  are you using?

Comment: I think that this question is fully answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181651/inspecting-websocket-frames-in-an-undetectable-way/31182643#31182643

Comment: @RobW you're right! Your answer to the question in that thread calls out one specific attribute of the content script called 'run_at:'document_start' that gets declared in content-script block of the the manifest, correct? Theoretically that is the golden key. It will allow me to 'monkey-patch' the constructor prior the WebSocket initialization to register my event handlers. There is a quite a bit of code in that snippet that I need to understand but, I think this approach will work. I will report back. Thanks!

Comment: @RChapps Indeed, running the script at document_start (before the page has executed other scripts that may use WebSocket) is the key here.

Comment: Well @RobW unfortunately I was not able to get this working. Your code itself seems to do exactly what it is supposed to do. However, I am still left with my original problem when integrating this functionality from within a chrome extension. I have provided a test repo with the bare minimum [here](https://github.com/RobbyChapman/DevTools-AlmostWorking) with logging. I have set 'run_at' to 'document_start', however the constructor does not get called. I have been using [this](http://kaazing.org/demos/echo/run/) as a test platform. Any help would be great appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @RChapps manifest.Jason should specify content_script_injector.js in content_scripts[0].js, but you used content_script.js

Comment: @RobW I am confused. The file 'content_script_injector.js' was just something I was playing around with. It isn't actually being invoked by anything at the moment. content_script.js is the actual script that contains the code to wrap the WebSocket at document_start. I thought that by assigning:

` "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]`

In the manifest would be sufficient since it points to the content script with related code. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @RChapps The [content script runs in an isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), so if you override the `WebSocket` constructor in the content script, then it is different from the page's. By injecting a script tag in the page, the script runs in the context of the page and then overriding the `WebSocket` constructor works.

Comment: @RobW After reading that article it all makes sense now. I was finally able to get this working late last night.  Within an isolated world, the DOM is shared, however in terms of JavaScript, it has it’s own isolated scope so to speak. That is where I went wrong; I was wrapping a copy of the constructor that was not exposed to the outside world. By injecting the content-script inline from an injector script, I was injecting code back into the page, which has the original WebSocket constructor of interest. Since the DOM is shared, I could then message back to the injector script via DOM events!

Answer (score 9):

you can wrap the WebSocket to spy on all instances created after you switch it:

```
(function(){

var ws = window.WebSocket;

window.WebSocket = function (a, b) {
   var that = b ? new ws(a, b) : new ws(a);
   that.addEventListener("open", console.info.bind(console, "socket open"));
   that.addEventListener("close", console.info.bind(console, "socket close"));
   that.addEventListener("message", console.info.bind(console, "socket msg"));
   return that;
};

window.WebSocket.prototype=ws.prototype; 

}());
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but had no luck. Below is a link to a fiddle I created. I am able to capture 'send' as usual, but not open, close, or error.

http://jsfiddle.net/s35zpfq9/

Comment: you just need to run the code above (or something like it)  before instantiating the socket: http://jsfiddle.net/s35zpfq9/2/ if that's not possible in your real app, the best you can do is intercept send(), which is not ideal...

Comment: This code strips out the constants on the WebSocket. I would add something like:

    for (var key in ws) {
      if (ws.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        window.WebSocket[key] = ws[key];
      }
    });

Comment: @AdamUllman: true, didn't know anyone would care... `Object.assign(window.WebSocket, ws);` would be a tad simpler way to restore them, but whatever works is good code.

Comment: Yes, good point, Object.assign is much nicer, I was just thinking about IE11 support.

The reason I came across this is because I use these constants in a library and then one of the users of this API had an issue because they were using this code to proxy the WebSocket which made my library stop working.