# Inspecting multiple WebSocket connections at the same time

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am using solutions provided in following topics to inspect WebSockets traffic (messages) on the web page, which I do not own (solely for learning purposes):

- [Inspecting WebSocket frames in an undetectable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181651/inspecting-websocket-frames-in-an-undetectable-way)
- [Listening to a WebSocket connection through prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712810/listening-to-a-websocket-connection-through-prototypes)
- https://gist.github.com/maskit/2252422

Like this:

```
(function(){
var ws = window.WebSocket;

window.WebSocket = function (a, b, c) {
   var that = c ? new ws(a, b, c) : b ? new ws(a, b) : new ws(a);
   that.addEventListener('open', console.info.bind(console, 'socket open'));
   that.addEventListener('close', console.info.bind(console, 'socket close'));
        that.addEventListener('message', console.info.bind(console, 'socket msg'));
        return that;
    };

    window.WebSocket.prototype=ws.prototype; 
}());
```

**The issue with the provided solutions is that they are listening on only 1 of 3 WebSocket connections ("wss://...").**  I am able to see in the console the messages that I receive or send, but only for one connection.. Is there something I am missing? Is it possible that two other service are any different and prohibiting the use of prototype extension technique?

p.s. I will not provide an URL to the web resource that I am doing my tests on, in order to avoid possible bans or legal questions.

Comment: There are two possibilities, I think. One is `iframe`s and the like. The other is that the value of `windows.WebSocket` is grabbed by other scripts before you can update it in your script and it just happens that one of them is doing it a little late.

Comment: @Ouroborus I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue.. there seemed to be no iframes.. So I used another approach which you can check in the answer section below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since it's been weeks and no answers, then I will post a solution which I ended up using.

I have built my own Chrome extension that listens to `WebSocket` connections and forwards all requests and responses to my own `WebSocket` `server` (which I happen to run in `C#`).

There are some limitations to this approach. You are not seeing the `request` `header` or who is sending the packets.. You are only able to see the `payload` and that is it. Also you are not able to modify the contents in any way or send your own requests (remember - you have no access to `header metadata`). Naturally, another limitation is that you have to be running `Chrome` (`devtools` `APIs` are used)..

*Some instructions.*

Here is how you attach debugger to listen to network packets:

```
    chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, "1.2", function () {
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, "Network.enable");
        chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onTabDebuggerEvent);
    });
```

Here is how you catch them:

```
function onTabDebuggerEvent(debuggeeId, message, params) {
    var debugeeTabId = debuggeeId.tabId;

    chrome.tabs.get(debugeeTabId, function (targetTab) {
        var tabUrl = targetTab.url;

        if (message == "Network.webSocketFrameSent") {

        }
        else if (message == "Network.webSocketFrameReceived") {
            var payloadData = params.response.payloadData;

            var request = {
                source: tabUrl,
                payload: params.response.payloadData
            };

            websocket.send(JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

Here is how you create a `websocket client`:

```
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:13529");

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (websocket.readyState !== 1) {
            console.log("Unable to connect to a WebsocketServer.");
            websocket = null;
        }
        else {
            console.log("WebsocketConnection started", websocket);

            websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
                console.log("WebSocket connection got closed!");

                if (evt.code == 3001) {
                    console.log('ws closed');
                } else {
                    console.log('ws connection error');
                }

                websocket = null;
            };

            websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
                console.log('ws normal error: ' + evt.type);
                websocket = null;
            };

        }
    }, 3000);
```

Creating the `server` is outside the scope of this question. You can use one in `Node.js`, `C#` or `Java`, whatever is preferable for you..

This is certainly not the most convenient approach, but unlike java-script injection method - it works in all cases.

**Edit:** totally forgot to mention. There seems to be another way of solving this, BUT I have not dig into that topic therefore maybe this is false info in some way. It should be possible to catch packets on a network interface level, through packet sniffing utilities. Such as `Wireshark` or `pcap`. Maybe something I will investigate further in the future :)