# Read websocket communication via userscript

Tags: javascript, websocket, userscripts

How can a greasemonkey script / Chrome's user-script intercept a running websocket communication?

My goal is to have additional statistics for a in-browser game

Comment: Are you also building the in-browser game? If so, I might recommend the pattern established by Redux Devtools, which is to provide a hook in the app that a Chrome plugin can hook into. Code at https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension, extension at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd

Comment: This comment shows a working tampermonkey script to intercept websocket communication: https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook/issues/5#issuecomment-531067029

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), then add the [Firebug module](https://www.getfirebug.com/) then add & use [websocket-monitor module](https://github.com/firebug/websocket-monitor/wiki)  to monitor websocket.

If you want to hook websocket from javascript you may also use [wshook](https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook).

Comment: Why not using this websocket hook inside your module: https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook

Comment: You may take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181651/inspecting-websocket-frames-in-an-undetectable-way

Answer (score 1):

Credit to: https://github.com/Cryoscalpel

> Not sure if this works in all ws games but you can create a proxy
> websocket message logger.

```
WebSocket.prototype.send = new Proxy(WebSocket.prototype.send, {
          apply: function(target, scope, args) {
             if(typeof(args[0]) === 'string') {
                let json = JSON.parse(args[0]);
                     console.log(json)
           }
                  let data = target.apply(scope, args);
                      return data;
        }
     })
```