# Change current page's javascript via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to write some javascript AJAX and Websocket hooking code in Chrome Extension.

Code is like below.

```
(function() {
        console.log("ajax hooking init");
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        ...  
    }
}
```

But, though above code do work, but it didn't hook any requests in current page. Do i something wrong? How to do hook some requests via chrome extension??

Comment: Since the content script runs in isolated world, you need to [put the hook in a script element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Looking at the advice _after_ the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31182643/934239) will help.